# XCode Source Control status constantly refreshing

Tags: xcode, git

I'm running XCode 6.1 and working with a git repo. XCode's source control is turned on, as well as the options Refresh local status automatically and Refresh server status automatically and Add or remove files automatically.

Every 10 seconds or so, xcode shows every file's status as changing to unknown (a question mark). After a bit, they mostly all refresh and show the correct status. This keeps happening over and over.

Why is this happening and how can I stop it?

They look like so:

Question Marks

[image: Question Marks]

Normal

[image: Normal status]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I have found the cause of this problem, and thus the solution.

My git repo was checked out on my local machine inside of another git repo by accident. Doing this cause massive confusion to XCode, apparently. Doing a fresh checkout in a different folder fixed the problem.

Answer (score -1):

To resolve this you need to do the following:

Go to Source Control -> Refresh Status.

It should solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks - believe it or not this did not do it. It does refresh everything, except afterwards, the constant refresh cycle continues.